# change default argument value built-in R function

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Setting Function Defaults R on a Project Specific Basis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9073912/setting-function-defaults-r-on-a-project-specific-basis)

I would like that when I call the built-in function table like this:

```
table(x)
```

the result be the same as if I call:

```
table(x, useNA='ifany')
```

i.e I don't want to explicitly set the argument 'useNA' every time I call this function.

More generally, how can we way to specify default behavior for built in function?

Comment: Answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9073912/setting-function-defaults-r-on-a-project-specific-basis)

Comment: Also answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4996090/271616).