# How to rewrite a function's default argument in R?

Tags: r, function, arguments, definition, redefinition

For example:

```
paste (..., sep = " ", collapse = NULL)
```

How can I rewrite this function in a way to make sure that each call will have `sep = ""` by default?

That is, how can I change the default values of arguments of functions I didn't write?

Comment: Why not use `paste0`, which comes with `sep = ""` as default?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
paste <- function(..., sep="", collapse=NULL) base::paste(...,sep=sep, collapse=collapse)
```

But for this there is already a function `paste0`.

Not also that if paste is called using the base namespace, it will use the default version.

Answer (score 3):

This is another way using `formals`.

```
paste.formals <- formals(paste)
paste.formals$sep <- ''
formals(paste, envir=.BaseNamespaceEnv) <- paste.formals
paste
# function (..., sep = "", collapse = NULL) 
# .Internal(paste(list(...), sep, collapse))
# <environment: namespace:base>
```

Comment: I don't get it, please explain your answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
paste("a","b") ## "a b"
library(Defaults)
```

An example that works:

```
mean(c(1,3,NA))  ## NA
setDefaults(mean.default,na.rm=TRUE)
mean(c(1,3,NA))  ## 2
```

But `paste()` is problematic:

```
setDefaults(paste,sep="")
## Error: evaluation nested too deeply:
##    infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
```

presumably because `paste()` is itself used within `setDefaults()`.

You're going to have some trouble overriding the default for this
function.  If you want to give us more context, in comments or
edits to the original question, we might have more sugestions.

**update**: one of the comments at [Setting Function Defaults R on a Project Specific Basis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9073912/setting-function-defaults-r-on-a-project-specific-basis) suggests that the problem with `paste()` is a bug rather than an intrinsic impossibility ...