# What does x[is.na(x)] do in R?

Tags: r, vector, indexing, idioms

I'm following the [swirl](http://swirlstats.com/) tutorial, and one of the parts has a vector x defined as:

```
> x
 [1]  1.91177824  0.93941777 -0.72325856  0.26998371          NA          NA
 [7] -0.17709161          NA          NA  1.98079386 -1.97167684 -0.32590760
[13]  0.23359408 -0.19229380          NA          NA  1.21102697          NA
[19]  0.78323515          NA  0.07512655          NA  0.39457671  0.64705874
[25]          NA  0.70421548 -0.59875008          NA  1.75842059          NA
[31]          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA
[37] -0.74265585          NA -0.57353603          NA
```

Then when we type `x[is.na(x)]` we get a vector of all `NA`'s

```
> x[is.na(x)]
 [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

Why does this happen? My confusion is that `is.na(x)` itself returns a vector of length 40 with `True` or `False` in each entry of the vector depending on whether that entry is `NA` or not. Why does "wrapping" this vector with x[ ] suddenly subset to the `NA`'s themselves?

Comment: When you index a vector by a logical vector, it returns the vector's elements where the index was `TRUE`. You can play with this yourself -- do `x <- c(1, 2, 3)`, and then do for instance `x[c(T, F, T)]`, `x[c(F, F, F)]`, etc.

Comment: The `[]` operator selects a subset of `x`. For example, `x[1:4]` returns the first four elements of `x`. When passed a logical vector, it instead returns all the elements of `x` for which the vector is `TRUE`. So `x[is.na(x)]` returns all the elements of `x` that are `NA`. Instead, `x[!is.na(x)]` would return all the non-`NA` elements of `x`.

Answer (score 3):

This is called **logical indexing**. It's a very common and neat R idiom.

Yes, `is.na(x)` gives a boolean ("logical") vector of same length as your vector.

Using that logical vector for indexing is called **logical indexing**.

Obviously `x[is.na(x)]` accesses the vector of all NA entries in x, and is totally pointless unless you intend to reassign them to some other value, e.g. impute the median (or anything else)

```
 x[is.na(x)] <- median(x, na.rm=T)
```

Notes:

- whereas `x[!is.na(x)]` accesses all non-NA entries in x
- or compare also to the `na.omit(x)` function, which is way more clunky
- The way R's builtin functions historically do (or don't) handle NAs (by default or customizably) is a patchwork-quilt mess, that's why the `x[is.na(x)]` idiom is so crucial)
- many useful functions (`mean, median, sum, sd, cor`) are NA-aware, i.e. they support an `na.rm=TRUE` option to ignore NA values. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31060373/202229). Also for how to define `table_, mode_, clamp_`