# Why are these means different when computed by dplyr mutate vs summarize in group_by?

Tags: r, dplyr, regression, aggregate, weighted-average

My dataframe contains:

- a column `deceased` on which I compute aggregated means later on (mortality ratios, by gender)
- a weighting variable `n.group`
- a categorical `sex` (1: female, 2: male)

I don't understand why the means and weighted-means `m.mortf, w.mortf` are wrong when calculated below in one single `mutate`/`summarize` expression.

Dataframe:

```
red11 <- structure(list(hosptg = structure(c(3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3"), class = "factor"), quarter.adm = structure(c(4L, 11L, 
3L, 12L, 7L, 8L, 12L, 9L, 1L, 11L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 10L, 10L, 
8L, 11L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 10L, 10L, 6L, 11L, 11L, 7L, 3L, 6L, 
10L, 12L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 12L, 4L, 4L, 12L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 11L, 
9L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 10L, 4L, 8L, 10L, 3L, 7L, 1L, 12L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 
6L, 3L, 9L, 7L, 8L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 11L, 9L, 11L, 1L, 
4L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 11L, 3L, 4L, 12L, 12L, 1L, 9L, 9L, 
6L, 9L, 1L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 9L, 11L), .Label = c("2011Q1", 
"2011Q2", "2011Q3", "2011Q4", "2012Q1", "2012Q2", "2012Q3", "2012Q4", 
"2013Q1", "2013Q2", "2013Q3", "2013Q4"), class = "factor"), g.mdc = c("08", 
"05", "09", "08", "14", "15", "15", "11", "09", "01", "08", "11", 
"16", "14", "08", "06", "08", "06", "06", "08", "15", "14", "14", 
"08", "11", "09", "08", "08", "06", "06", "06", "08", "03", "05", 
"05", "15", "02", "05", "08", "04", "04", "10", "06", "01", "08", 
"05", "03", "06", "01", "01", "06", "08", "08", "04", "12", "05", 
"01", "15", "08", "01", "08", "01", "05", "15", "15", "01", "06", 
"15", "01", "08", "01", "05", "08", "02", "15", "03", "06", "05", 
"05", "03", "09", "08", "11", "12", "06", "04", "08", "01", "06", 
"01", "08", "06", "15", "05", "08", "07", "08", "13", "08", "08"
), sex = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
    age = c(23L, 83L, 51L, 54L, 37L, 0L, 0L, 82L, 45L, 88L, 84L, 
    58L, 41L, 33L, 71L, 79L, 67L, 42L, 73L, 66L, 0L, 26L, 38L, 
    65L, 31L, 87L, 38L, 38L, 77L, 44L, 54L, 74L, 38L, 70L, 44L, 
    0L, 78L, 65L, 56L, 85L, 70L, 83L, 89L, 46L, 39L, 34L, 5L, 
    85L, 18L, 5L, 41L, 73L, 18L, 41L, 75L, 77L, 36L, 0L, 84L, 
    83L, 58L, 93L, 83L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 49L, 0L, 55L, 46L, 40L, 81L, 
    60L, 51L, 0L, 22L, 78L, 69L, 75L, 65L, 31L, 15L, 79L, 87L, 
    72L, 78L, 48L, 16L, 81L, 63L, 84L, 17L, 0L, 60L, 60L, 74L, 
    44L, 44L, 53L, 71L), deceased = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
    n.group = c(3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .Names = c("hosptg", "quarter.adm", "g.mdc", 
"sex", "age", "deceased", "n.group"), row.names = c(NA, -100L
))
```

**Grouping - using `mutate`:**

```
red111 <- red11 %>%
  group_by(hosptg, quarter.adm, g.mdc)  %>%
    mutate(n=n(),
      female = mean(sex == '1', na.rm=T), 
      age = mean(age, na.rm=T),
      m.mortf = mean(deceased == '1', na.rm=T),
      w.mortf = weighted.mean(deceased == '1', n.group, na.rm=T))
```

**Grouping - using `summarize`** (i.e. aggregation):

```
red211 <- red11 %>%
  group_by(hosptg, quarter.adm, g.mdc) %>%  
  summarize(n=n(),
    female  = mean(sex == '1', na.rm=T),
    age     = mean(age, na.rm=T),
    m.mortf = mean(deceased == '1', na.rm=T),
    w.mortf = weighted.mean(deceased == '1', n.group, na.rm=T))
```

I would have expected the ratio being the same and foremost keeping the initial mean. I understand what the aggregation does this is also illustrated by the `sum(redxx$n)` but I struggle comprehending the full background.

Initial data frame mean:

```
 mean(red11$deceased == 1, na.rm=T)  [1] 0.02
```

Mutate mean and sum:

```
sum(red211$n)           [1] 170
> mean(red111$female)   [1] 0.52
> mean(red111$w.mortf)  [1] 0.02
> mean(red111$m.mortf)  [1] 0.02
```

Summarized mean and sum:

```
sum(red211$n)           [1] 100
mean(red211$female)     [1] 0.4977169
mean(red211$w.mortf)    [1] 0.02739726
mean(red211$m.mortf)    [1] 0.02739726
```

What I would like to have is an aggregated data frame (i.e. reduced number of lines) maintaining the initial mean throughout. And, why does the weighting variable not compensate for it?

**EDIT:** 
My basic intention is that I am using a big data file where I have single entries where a case may be deceased. Then I calculate mortality ratios. But this can logically only be done at aggregated level. That is why I create a data frame like red211. Thereafter I base my regression models on it. But them again means are based on that second data frame and not the original values. Thus my results are distorted in size. That is why I am "desperately" looking for a solution that will get me closer to my original mean values. I hope this helps.

The model I use is a straight forward difference in difference:

```
lm(w.mortf ~ treatment * year, data = red)
```

where: treatment is the treatment group / year the intervention year / red the aggregated data frame

```
===========================================================
             w.mortf                m.mortf             
-----------------------------------------------------------
(Intercept)    0.037 (0.001) ***       0.037 (0.001) ***
year           0.003 (0.001) *         0.003 (0.001) *  
tg1           -0.003 (0.001) *        -0.003 (0.001) *  
year:tg1      -0.001 (0.002)          -0.001 (0.002)    
-----------------------------------------------------------
Adj. R^2          0.000                   0.000            
Num. obs.    126031                  126031                
RMSE              0.172                   0.179            
===========================================================
```

The original data frame mean is approx. 0.018 - thus I think to far away from being interpretable - or where I am misled?

The figure below illustrates the issue. Where 2012Q1 should be the reference value findable based on the above regression.

[image: three groups showing weighted means based on aggregated data]

Comment: What is the expected `n` supposed to be?

Comment: I would have said that is should maintain the same count of cases stemming from the original data.frame.

Comment: Normally we complain about not enough data or MCVE, but here there's way too much irrelevant data and code obscuring your question, which is buried: **why can't you compute weighted-mean in the same dplyr aggregate that creates the variables you'll use to do aggregating?** Can you please move the question statement to the top, and make it clearer?

Comment: Please delete the model `lm(w.mortf ~ ...)` and the graph, we don't need them. As to the mutate repeatedly using `mean(..., na.rm=T)`, I usually [define `mean_   <- function(...) mean(..., na.rm=T)` for legibility](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31060373/202229)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to apply the weighting after aggregation:

```
red311 <- red11 %>% 
  group_by(hosptg, quarter.adm, g.mdc)  %>%  
  summarize(n= n()
            , female    = mean(sex == '1', na.rm=T) 
            , age       = mean(age, na.rm=T)
            , m.mortf   = mean(deceased == '1', na.rm=T))
weighted.mean(red311$female, red311$n)
#> [1] 0.52
weighted.mean(red311$m.mortf, red311$n)
#> [1] 0.02
```

*Edit:* If the (unweighted) averages in `red311` would correspond to the averages in `red11`, then the values in `red311`would be pretty meaningless. One can see this by going through the math or from a simple example:

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))
df <- data.frame(key = c('a', 'b', 'b', 'b'), value = 1:4, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df
#>   key value
#> 1   a     1
#> 2   b     2
#> 3   b     3
#> 4   b     4
mean(df$value)
#> [1] 2.5
df1 <- df %>%
  group_by(key) %>%
  summarize(n = n(), value = mean(value)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(weighted = value * n * n() / sum(n))
df1
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#>   key       n value weighted
#>   <chr> <int> <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 a         1  1.00    0.500
#> 2 b         3  3.00    4.50
mean(df1$value)
#> [1] 2
mean(df1$weighted)
#> [1] 2.5
weighted.mean(df1$value, df1$n)
#> [1] 2.5
```

So while it is possible to introduce the `weighted` column with average equal to the original average, the values in there are pretty meaningless from my point of view.

*Edit 2:* The re-weighting schema used above is general and can also be applied to the original data:

```r
red411 <- red11 %>% 
  group_by(hosptg, quarter.adm, g.mdc)  %>%  
  summarize(n= n()
            , female    = mean(sex == '1', na.rm=T) 
            , age       = mean(age, na.rm=T)
            , m.mortf   = mean(deceased == '1', na.rm=T)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(w.mortf = m.mortf * n * n() / sum(n))
mean(red411$w.mortf)
#> [1] 0.02
```

However, I am unsure how to interpret `w.mortf`.

Comment: @chrischi Can you use the normal averages together with the weights in your regression? Anyway, I think https://stats.stackexchange.com/ is better suited for that question.

Comment: @chrischi No, I meant aggregation plus averaging like in my original answer. Using appropriate weights with these averages gave the right means. They might give the right regressions, too, when used with weights. To make the question more tool oriented (again): Can you share the code for the regression you are trying to do?

Comment: Have you tried `lm(m.mortf ~ treatment * year, data = red, weights = n)` using data aggregated with `summarize` as above?

Comment: @chrischi I am surprised that the results are the same, but cannot reproduce this with the given information. Can you provide a minimal example showing all steps from the posted data to your model?

Comment: @chrischi I prefer expessing this as code: `weighted.mean(red211$m.mortf, red211$n) == mean(red11$deceased == '1')` returns `TRUE`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: My current answer is: 
I use the unweighted coefficient as outcome and apply the number of cases per aggregated group as weighting factor. As proposed above. This renders a close enough result graphically. Despite the need to run the graphs on the red11 data frame.