# Summarize data by group and column name

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have the following data frame

```
library(tidyverse)    
ID <- c('A','A','B','C','D','E','F')
Level1 <- c(20,50,30,10,15,10,NA)
Level2 <- c(40,33,84,NA,20,1,NA)
Level3 <- c(60,40,60,10,25,NA,NA)
Grade1 <- c(20,50,30,10,15,10,NA)
Grade2 <- c(40,33,84,NA,20,1,NA)

DF <- data.frame(ID,Level1,Level2,Level3,Grade1,Grade2)
  ID Level1 Level2 Level3 Grade1 Grade2
1  A     20     40     60     20     40
2  A     50     33     40     50     33
3  B     30     84     60     30     84
4  C     10     NA     10     10     NA
5  D     15     20     25     15     20
6  E     10      1     NA     10      1
7  F     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
```

My goal is to group the data by ID, summarize the columns with columnname containing the string "Level" by calculating the mean value. Ideally, the output should look something like this

```
ID        mean (Level1+Level2+Level3)
A         40.5
B         58
C         10
....
```

Here is my code

```
DF %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  select(starts_with('Level')) %>%
  summarise(mean(.,na.rm = TRUE))
```

When I run the code, I get the following output

```
Adding missing grouping variables: `ID`
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  ID    `mean(., na.rm = TRUE)`
  <fct>                   <dbl>
1 A                          NA
2 B                          NA
3 C                          NA
4 D                          NA
5 E                          NA
6 F                          NA
Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(., na.rm = TRUE) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In mean.default(., na.rm = TRUE) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
3: In mean.default(., na.rm = TRUE) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
4: In mean.default(., na.rm = TRUE) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
5: In mean.default(., na.rm = TRUE) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
6: In mean.default(., na.rm = TRUE) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

Cloud you please help me understand what wrong with my code. For proposed solutions 1) columns should be selected by matching column names against a string using functions like starts_with() or contains() in dplyr. 2) I would also like to avoid pivoting or gather functions if that possible.

I appreciate your help

Comment: Possible duplicate: [*Aggregate / summarize multiple variables per group (e.g. sum, mean)*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9723208/2204410)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Aggregate / summarize multiple variables per group (e.g. sum, mean)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723208/aggregate-summarize-multiple-variables-per-group-e-g-sum-mean)

Comment: Personally [I recommend defining NA-aware functions like `mean_`, `median_` etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31060373/202229)

Comment: How do you want to treat na value?

Comment: Ideally, na.rm = TRUE if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eidt: Updated answer aggregating across "Level" columns.

```
DF %>%
  gather(col, value, -ID) %>%
  filter(col %>% str_starts("Level")) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(value, na.rm = TRUE))

## A tibble: 6 x 2
#  ID     mean
#  <fct> <dbl>
#1 A      40.5
#2 B      58  
#3 C      10  
#4 D      20  
#5 E       5.5
#6 F     NaN
```

---

Orig answer
Here's a variant of what Sang won kim wrote that works for me with dplyr 0.8.3, the current CRAN version.

```
DF %>%
  group_by(ID)  %>%
  summarise_at(vars(starts_with('Level')), mean, na.rm = TRUE)

# A tibble: 6 x 4
  ID    Level1 Level2 Level3
  <fct>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 A         35   36.5     50
2 B         30   84       60
3 C         10  NaN       10
4 D         15   20       25
5 E         10    1      NaN
6 F        NaN  NaN      NaN
```

Comment: Hi Jon, I would the mean for the 3 columns combined, and separately. Please check my desired outcome in the question I posted.

Comment: Thanks Jon. Is there a solution without converting the dataframe into the long format?

Comment: When I run your modified code, I get the following error msg: Error: Evaluation error: could not find function "str_starts".

Comment: `str_starts` is from `stringr` which should be loaded with `library(tidyverse)` as in OP.  https://www.tidyverse.org/packages/

Comment: I have imported tidyverse and stringr  and still getting the error msg.

Comment: Looks like `str_starts` was added in stringr 1.4.0 in February.  You could use `str_detect("Level")` alternatively, it would however detect later occurrences of the phrase, like in `RD_Level`. https://github.com/tidyverse/stringr/releases/tag/v1.4.0

Answer (score 0):

```
DF %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  select(starts_with('Level')) %>%
  summarise_all(funs(mean(.,na.rm = TRUE)))
```

or

```
DF %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  select(starts_with('Level')) %>%
  summarise_all(list(~mean(.,na.rm = TRUE)))
```

You can get this :

```
  ID    Level1 Level2 Level3
  <fct>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 A         35   36.5     50
2 B         30   84       60
3 C         10  NaN       10
4 D         15   20       25
5 E         10    1      NaN
6 F        NaN  NaN      NaN
```

Comment: @Jon Spring Isn't work summarise_all(list(~mean(.,na.rm = TRUE)))?

Comment: It seems like to be similar to bug that have occurred in the past. I'll look for a little more. Sry. (https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/643)

Comment: Aha! I had the `raster` package loaded from a prior question, noted in the issue as a problem. Restarting fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: @Sangwonkim I need the means to be aggregated rather than separate. Please refer to my edited question.